# Show tint effect when info window is tapped in google Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, infowindow

I am creating a InfoWindow by using the following method,

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

And I am handling the event related to tapping of InfoWindow using,

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

But I want to show a tint effect when the InfoWindow is tapped. I want to implement this effect with google maps.This effect can be seen in Apple Maps. In Apple maps if you drop a pin and the tap the InfoWindow it shows the tint effect. I want to implement this feature like Apple maps in google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Official Google documention for [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker#properties), it is not possible to customize the infowindow's color however there is a work around for that. What you can do is to insert images as a background to make it tinted.

I found a video tutorial which discuss how to insert images using GMSMa[ViewDelegate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILiBXYscsyY